# Less files - django usage

Tags: django, less, django-compressor, django-static

I bought a template for my project which has 'less' files along with other static files and templates.

Any suggestions where to put them?

Also, there are 3 django package to use for 'less' files..  [django-static-compiler](https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-static-precompiler), [django-compressor](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/)  [django-css](https://github.com/dziegler/django-css)  to execute these files.

Please help me which one should i use and why these packages are needed. Thanks!

Edit - Found out that Django-css is dead. Please help me choose from other 2 packages

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you don't need to use less in your frontend [directly](http://lesscss.org/usage/#using-less-in-the-browser), but you need to use a result of compilation of your less files - usual css style files. Look in your template css files, which already compiled from your less. Less files provided by template developer for extra customization purposes.

So the question is how to compile your less? You can do it with various of ways, [with python implementation](https://github.com/lesscpy/lesscpy) of less compiler, with using of [less npm package](https://github.com/less/less.js) for node.js, with some kind of [gui less compiler](http://lesscss.org/usage/#guis-for-less) or even with many [online less compilers](http://lesscss.org/usage/#online-less-compilers).

Generally, compilation is pretty easy; you specify your input less files and output css directory, when compiler do all work for you.

Comment: My question is that I already have 'less' files in template i bought. Do i still need to compile them? Can't I directly use them?

Comment: I can't be 100% sure with no template watched, but most probably you don't need to compile the less files if you have css files in your template. This css files must be compiled from those less files by the author of template. If you can, please provide the structure of your template.

Comment: I mean structure of files and directories of your template. It helps me to figure out do you need to have a deal with compiling of less of not.

Comment: I've kept templates as ... templates->music(app-name)->html files   and static->less->less files. Static folder has my img, js, css folders as well.